# creating nice looking output in r

Tags: r, output

I am making a number of calculations from a dataset and I want to display the end results in a structured and ordered way in a txt document.

So far I have tried something which  is really messy but it kinda works (see below), but I'm sure there are better and more elegant solutions. When using cbind, I get the [,1]   [,2] etc labels on top of my data and I don't need them in my output.

```
  id = c(1, 2,3,4)
  age = c(10, 12, 14, 17)
  gender = c("m", "f", "m", "f")
  dataset = data.frame (id,age, gender)
  attach (dataset)
  space = "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
  print1 = summary (dataset)
  print2 = cbind("age oldest student", max(age))
  printfull = capture.output(print1, space, print2, space)
  write.table(printfull, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/dataset123.txt")
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your question, exactly?  There are *lots* of different solutions out there: brew, Sweave, knitr, and the `describe` function of Hmisc spring to mind, although several of them assume LaTeX rather than plain-text output

Comment: I just want a document which displays all my output (summary, max values, median, some calculations, ... in a readable way, one calculation below the previous one...preferably with some labels. The capture.output function does that, which is great for the summary function, but gives too much irrelevant stuff like "[,1]". I would prefer this in word or notepad, not in LaTex

Comment: Can you tell us why it is important that it be in a text file? If you are looking for human readability I'm not sure .txt files are your best bet. In that case I recommend Knitr as easy to work with yet fairly powerful.

Comment: can you loop to make multiple knitr documents at the same time? I'm making an analysis of multiple variables but I'm doing this on 200 similarly sized datasets with different values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RJSONIO to convert your r objects into json

```
library('RJSONIO')
toJSON(list(list(1,2,3),1,2,4:5))
```

Comment: Ha. I'm pretty sure that OP wants *human* readable, not *computer* readable.

Comment: well i think a json with pretty print is very human readable :), given the generic nature of problem where there are tons of different types.